# Printing a number triangle

Tags: java, loops

CS student here. I've just received an introduction to loops and I'm not sure I understand them very well. I'm trying to print a triangle of numbers `n`, such that if `n = 4` you'd get something like this:

```
         4
      3  7
   2  6  9
1  5  8 10
```

Instead I'm winding up with something like:

```
   4
3   5
```

Suffice it to say I'm lost. Here's my code:

```
void drawT3 (int n)
{
    int k = 1;
    int t = 1;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {  
        k = n;
        int j;
        for (j=1;j<=n-i;j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for (j=1;j<=t;j++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%3d",k);
            k += (n - j);
        }
        n--;
        t++;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you've posted your expected output for n=4, but then you post actual output for n=2?

Comment: @SamIam I think that is his actual output for `n=4`. Look at this: `n--;` This will get run twice for `n=4`.

Comment: If I were you, I'd make a 2d array to represent your output, and fill everywhere where there should be white-space with `-1`, and then I'd systematically print the contents of the array.  padding each value until it takes 3 spaces to print.  That way you don't have to deal with such complex logic

Answer (score 2):

```
void printTriangle(int n)
{ 
    // build an auxiliary 2D array
    final int t[][] = new int[n][n];
    int i = 1;
    for (int s = n - 1; s <= 2 * (n - 1); s++)
    {
        for (int x = s - n + 1; x < n; x++)
        {
            t[x][s - x] = i++;
        }
    }
    // print the array
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            if (t[x][y] > 0)
            {
                System.out.printf("%3d", t[x][y]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.printf("   ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(); // start new line
    }
}
```

1. Build an auxiliary 2D array of size `n`.
2. Put numbers into array as human will do, from 1 to n, following the diagonals. `s` in the code represents `x + y` sum. That sum is constant for every diagonal. In the first diagonal (the longest one) sum is equal to `n - 1`. In the second diagonal sum is 1 more, `n`. In the last "diagonal" (bottom right corner) the sum is `2 * (n - 1)`. That's exactly our loop: `for (int s = n - 1; s <= 2 * (n - 1); s++)`. Having the sum and `x` we can obtain `y` with simple subtraction, `y = s - x`.
3. Print the array. Each cell of array is initialized with 0 (`int`'s default value). So, if a cell has zero, we just print 3 spaces, to preserve the shape of triangle.

PS. My code was written for "educational purposes" :) To show how it can be done, in easy way. It's not optimized for speed nor memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n=4,i,j,k,t;
for (i=n;i>=1;i--)
{  
    t=i;
    k=n;
    for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        System.out.printf("   ");  // for leading spaces

    System.out.printf("%3d",i);   // for first digit(or number) in each row (in your example these are 4,3,2,1)

    for(j=i;j<n;j++)
    {
        t+=k;   
        System.out.printf("%3d",t);
        k--;
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

OUTPUT:
for n=8

```
                      8
                   7 15
                6 14 21
             5 13 20 26
          4 12 19 25 30
       3 11 18 24 29 33
    2 10 17 23 28 32 35
 1  9 16 22 27 31 34 36
```

http://ideone.com/C1O1GS

make space around numbers according to your need.

PS: I would never suggest to write any pattern code using array unless it is very complicated. array will use extra memory space.

Comment: If a first year turn a loop like this in to me (and had not already demonstrated a clear mastery of the lanaguage in previous assingments) I would wonder where he copied it from. This even has comma list initializition, which is really not popular in java, and signifies someone who probably learned to code in older languages. So be careful copying this!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    triangle(4);
}

static public void triangle(int n){
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = n;i>0;i--){
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        x = i+n;
        for (int j=0;j<n-i;j++){
            System.out.print(x - j + " ");
            x = x + n -j;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Output for 4:

4

3 7

2 6 9

1 5 8 10

Output for 6:

6

5 11

4 10 15

3 9 14 18

2 8 13 17 20

1 7 12 16 19 21

Answer (score 1):

Observe that there are many ways to print out a triangle of numbers as described above,  For example, here are two,

```
// for n=5,
// 1  2  3  4  5
//    6  7  8  9
//      10 11 12
//         13 14
//            15
```

And

```
//             5
//          4  9
//       3  8 12
//    2  7 11 14
// 1  6 10 13 15
```

And since recursion is ***Fun!***

```
class triangle
{
    //Use recursion,
    static int rowUR( int count, int start, int depth )
    {
        int ndx;
        if(count<=0) return start;
        //-depth?
        for (ndx=0;ndx<depth;ndx++)
        {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        //how many? 5-depth, 5,4,3,2,1
        for( ndx=0; ndx<count; ++ndx )
        {
            System.out.printf("%3d",start+ndx);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
        if( count>0 )
        {
            rowUR( count-1, ndx+start, depth+1 );
        }
        return ndx;
    }
    //Use recursion,
    static int rowLR( int count, int start, int depth )
    {
        int ndx, accum;
        if( start < count )
            rowLR( count, start+1, depth+1 );
        for( ndx=0; ndx<depth; ++ndx )
        {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        accum=start;
        //how many? 5-depth, 1,2,3,4,5
        for( ndx=0; ndx<(count-depth); ++ndx )
        {
            System.out.printf("%3d",accum);
            accum+=count-ndx;
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
        return ndx;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int count=4, depth=0, start=1;
        System.out.printf("rowUR\n");
        rowUR( count=5, start=1, depth=0 );
        System.out.printf("rowLL\n");
        rowLL( count=5, start=1, depth=0 );
    }
};
```